# Following 302 Redirect with Ruby Mechanize

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

When I run this in Chrome and turn off JavaScript, the redirect still works, so I don't think this is a JavaScript issue.

Looking at the network tab of the Developer Tools, I see that the first page that comes back upon submission is the same page as the original URL (searchOW.aspx), and then a 302 redirect is issued to send to the results page (searchResultAward1.aspx).

However, when I run my Mechanize script, it just stays on the original page and doesn't follow the redirect. My understanding of Mechanize is that it follows redirects like this by default.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new { |agent|
  agent.user_agent_alias = "Mac Safari"
}
agent.log = Logger.new('mechanize.log')

united_search_page_uri = 'http://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/booking/flight/searchOW.aspx?CS=N'

agent.get(united_search_page_uri) do |page|

puts page.inspect

search_result = page.form_with(:name => 'aspnetForm') do |search|
  search["ctl00$ContentInfo$SearchForm$Airports1$Origin$txtOrigin"] = "BOS"
  search["ctl00$ContentInfo$SearchForm$Airports1$Destination$txtDestination"] = "SFO"
  search["ctl00$ContentInfo$SearchForm$DateTimeCabin1$Depdate$txtDptDate"] = "3/15/2015"
  search["ctl00$ContentInfo$SearchForm$TripTypes"] = 'rdoOW'
  search["ctl00_ContentInfo_SearchForm_searchBy_rdosearchby3"] = "rdosearchby3"
 end.submit

 end

 File.open("temp.html", 'w+') do |f|
   f.puts search_result.parser.to_html
 end

 puts "----------------------------"
 puts search_result.title
 puts search_result.uri
 puts search_result.response
 puts search_result.code
```

Anyone have any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: Your code is invalid. It appears to be missing a trailing `end` at least. It needs to be runnable for us to help you.

Comment: code should now be runnable in irb

Comment: Is it that you're inspecting the wrong page? You want to inspect `search_result` I think.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking at search_result. I added some debugging output here to show the output.